# PostgreSQL 9.5 : Display json data into table

Tags: json, postgresql

I have the following record in the table `table_json`:

**Table**:

```
  id        doc
  ---------------------------------------
  1 
            {"name":"Shaw",
                 "address":{"line1":"L1",
                            "line2":"L2",
                            "zipcode":"12345"
                           }
            }
```

Note: Column `doc` is of type `json`. Now i want to print the json data into the form of 
the following one.

**Expected output**:

```
  id    name    address
  --------------------------
   1    Shaw    L1,L2,12345
```

Comment: You can go through https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html and use the functions accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `json_each_text()` in lateral join:

```
with a_table (id, doc) as (
values
(1, '{
    "name": "Shaw", 
    "address":{
        "line1":"L1",
        "line2":"L2",
        "zipcode":"12345"
        }
    }'::json)
)
select 
    id, 
    doc->>'name' as name, 
    string_agg(value, ',') as address
from a_table, 
lateral json_each_text(doc->'address')
group by 1, 2;

 id | name |   address   
----+------+-------------
  1 | Shaw | L1,L2,12345
(1 row)
```